# 'NoneType' object is not iterable in loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, selenium-webdriver

I am assuming I am making a mistake in assigning  links to equal the driver.get statement.  I need to loop within the page until it grabs all the links but I am messing up somewhere.  I keep getting the error of "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" in the line "for link in links:"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

b = open('csv/homedepotfridges.csv', 'w', newline='')
a = csv.writer(b,delimiter=',')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
links = driver.get('https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/appliances/refrigerators-and-freezers/refrigerators.html')

for link in links:
    name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-name')
    model = driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-model')
    price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('product-display-price')
    detail = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-detail-link')

    for x, y, z, q in zip(name, model, price, detail):
        c= (x.text, y.text, z.text, q.get_attribute("href"))
        print (x.text, y.text, z.text, q.get_attribute("href"))
        a.writerow(c)

b.close()
```

Comment: "utterable"? Surely the error says "iterable"?

Comment: Thanks.  Autocorrect I guess changed it

Answer (score 0):

Selenium webdrivers don't return anything from their `get` method, and in fact the `get` method may return before the web page has even started loading. See the documentation for [waiting for content](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference).

Comment: When I use this for a single link it works perfectly.  I just need it to loop many times on the page

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you about that. The [selenium documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations) states that the web page is not necessarily loaded completely or at all by the `get` method, depending on various factors, and the [get method does not return a value](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L244).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to:

go to the page
make a list of all the products
read and write certain properties of those products.

If that is correct then:

1) go to the page with driver.get (no need to assign it, since get doesn't return anything)

2) make a list. something like link = driver.find_elements_by_classname('product-details')

3) then iterate over the list using for link in links:

and find the specific property within the product, something like:
product_href = link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')

and do something awesome with it!

Does this help ?